# Handle mutated while enumerated crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sometimes I see a crash in my iOs app at this line:

```
  NSNumber *index = [[self.objectByIndex allKeysForObject:obj] lastObject];
```

The crash is "enumerated while mutated".

The method containing the above line of code is called frequently ...

What is the best way to fix this ? Should I just put this line in a @synchronize block?

Comment: You first need to find out what code is modifying `objectByIndex` so that you can also lock it.  (I tend to prefer explicit locks and queues because if you ever have a second reason for using `@synchronized` in the same class, things get confusing.)

Comment: It means that somewhere you're enumerating an object (eg, `for(NSNumber* x in someArray)`) and somewhere else you're "mutating" the object -- adding or removing elements.  Don't do that.  It's possible it's due to multithreading, in which case you need to think long and hard about your design.  But usually it's code in a single thread doing this.

Comment: And you **must** always quote the *entire* and *exact* error message when reporting a crash on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your obj is being enumerated while you are trying to access it. Copy the contents of your obj into a newobj and retrieve your `NSNumber` from that.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have a race condition. An other thread is modifying your obj while it is enumarated to find lastObject from allKeys. Therefore you must redesign your code to be multithread safe.

btw if this code is frequently called, perhaps it is better to use an array instead of a dictionary because you can retreive the last object of an array much faster then the one of a dictionary.